# Is there a temple in India where devotees get rid of the "evil" in their selves by uttering abusive words before a deity?

Tags: temple

I came across the following bit on this [Christian Evangelist website []](https://probe.org/how-can-my-hindu-friend-justify-her-unethical-behavior/):

> [...]there is a temple in India where they have a festival every year.
> Devotees go there during this festival that goes for a week and utter
> curses and abuses to the god in that temple. These are the worst words
> (@#$&*^#%) you can imagine. They do it with the belief that this is a
> way of bringing out all the evil thoughts and anger in them and this
> god can take it so that they can get cleaned from all the dirt inside
> them.

Is there any such temple in India?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Kodungallur Bhagavathy Temple located in Kerala is one such temple. It is dedicated to the goddess Bhadrakali, who was born from third eye of Lord Shiva and had slain the asura Darika

They have a month long festival known as Bharani festival which falls in the month of April/May. A significant ritual of this festival is "Kaavu Theendal" (polluting the temple"). In this ritual, "Vellichappadu" ( oracles of goddess) run around the temple in a frenzied trance state, waving their sickle-shaped swords in the air. They yell out lewd, and abusive cries at the goddess

One can find several YouTube videos showing the above. A couple are [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FC77ItqJhWQ) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwD-IWN2hfM)

To those who find it strange, please understand that this is a form of Virodhi bhakti, which is an acceptable form of worship. As per Shiva Gita 7.21

> अनादरेण शाठ्येन परिहासेन मायया

> शिवभक्तिरतश्चेत्स्यादन्त्यजोऽपि विमुच्यते

> Anyone while doing criticism, or while disrespecting, or due to jealousy, if gets devoted or gains devotion for Shiva, he would get cleansed of all the Sins immediately.